# java shared variables

Tags: java

I was wondering how multiple threads could access the same variable.  If the variable is non static and each thread is its own thread object, how can you access the same variable?  For instance supposed I have a function that finds the maximum of a 2D array.  If each thread finds the maximum of a row, and each thread also maintains a local maximum of that row and compares that local maximum to a shared maximum and updates the shared maximum accordingly, how would you access the shared maximum if you have different thread objects?

For example in this code i have

```
for(int i=0; i<input.length; i++){
rowArray = input[i];
teste r1 = new teste(rowArray);
runnables.add(r1);
}
```

this calls the teste class which implements runnable, and instantiates it with a row of the array.  Then it adds it to an arraylist of runnables.  Now, each teste object has its own variable and reference, so how would you be able to "share" them if you are creating different teste objects for each row?  Basically i want to pass by reference instead of value >,>

Answer (score 1):

The threads need to have a way to refer to the same "shared maximum" value in your example.

Two ways of doing that are:

- have the maximum be a static variable (dubious)
- pass the "maximum" object as a parameter to your thread when you create it

Note that when multiple threads are accessing the same variable, you must take steps to synchronize access to it (so two threads aren't simultaneously modifying it.

One way to do that is with a `synchronized` statemtned

Comment: Yeah, so I tried passing it as a parameter to the thread as a constructor.  Unfortunately that passes by value instead of reference=/

Comment: I gave an upvote, however you have missed several alternatives for "sharing" variables -- and thus objects (these do not address thread-safety in any way): 1) In the object implementing Runnable, use a member variable (can mutate the object) 2) If the runnable objects are created from non-static nested classes you can refer to the parents non-static members (can mutate or assign) 3) If the runnable objects are created from anonymous inner classes you can access `final` variables in scope (can mutate the object).

Comment: Also, just to be pedantic, the problem is more general that assigning to variables -- *any* shared object modifications must be correctly protected to avoid potential concurrency-induced errors.

Answer (score 0):

Java provides the [volatile modifier for variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable#In_Java), which guarantees that each thread will read its current value instead of a thread-cached value.